# FFTW plan rountine returns back null

Tags: c, windows, visual-studio-2012, fftw

I need someone with experience using [FFTW](http://www.fftw.org/)

I am writing a program which needs to do a real to complex transform, but my planning routine returns back null and I am not sure why. I am passing valid integer parameters for the size, and non-NULL pointers for the array. I have consulted the documentation but all it says is that if it cannot make the plan it returns NULL, but besides doing the opposite of what I mentioned above, it does not list any other reasons for my plan failing. Below is piece of sample code

```
int size ={64, 128, 256};

float *spatial = malloc(size[1]*size[1]*sizeof(float));
fftwf_complex *fourier = fftwf_alloc_complex(size[1]*size[1]);

for(int i=0; i< size[1]; i++){
    for(int j=0; j<size[1]; j++){
        spatial = //fill spatial array;
    }
}

for(int i=0; i< size[1]; i++){
    for(int j=0; j<size[1]; j++){
        fourier = //fill fourier array;
    }
}

fftwf_plan plan = fftwf_plan_dft_r2c_2d(size[1], size[1], spatial, fourier, FFTW_FORWARD);
fftwf_execute(plan);
```

the  `fftwf_plan_dft_r2c_2d()` continually returns back NULL for `plan` and I am not sure why

Note: I am using Windows 8.1 with Visual Studios 2012

Comment: Use `fftw_malloc` (or `fftwf_alloc_real `) rather than `malloc` to allocate `spatial`, otherwise alignment is not guaranteed.

Comment: I tried both, no dice

Comment: Make sure both `fourier` and `spatial` are non-NULL. Also make sure that the code for filling the arrays is not buggy, otherwise you may be corrupting the heap prior to the call to `fftwf_plan_dft_r2c_2d` - try commenting out these loops temporarily to see if it makes a difference.

Comment: I tried both of those things before I posted, no luck. Could the libraries not properly be installed?

Comment: I suppose it's possible that the program is not finding the FFTW DLL, or something like that - I'm not really a Windows person, but I did get FFTW to work on Windows once, and it was a lot of hassle. On Mac OS X or Linux it just works, but Windows always seems to be problematic. Can you switch to Linux or are you stuck with Windows ?

Comment: For my purposes, I am stuck with windows

Comment: The fftw dll would be have to be in the System32 folder correct?

Comment: OK - bad luck then - all I can suggest is dumping all the .dll .lib .exp files etc into the executable's directory and hope for the best...

Comment: I don't know - I usually put it in the same directory as the .exe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to reproduce your problem on ubuntu...
The problem comes from the flag `FFTW_FORWARD` used by `fftwf_plan_dft_r2c_2d`. I don't know where it is documented, but it is not working. The reason is that `fftwf_plan_dft_r2c_2d` is always a forward transform, the backward transform being `fftwf_plan_dft_c2r_2d`

Moreover, you can reduce the memory footprint of your program. Indeed, in case of r2c transforms, only half the complex coefficients are computed and stored. Hence, the array allocated by `fftwf_alloc_complex(size[1]*size[1]);` is about twice the needed size. Take a look at [the documentation](http://www.fftw.org/doc/Multi_002dDimensional-DFTs-of-Real-Data.html) to know more about the extra padding and the layout of frequencies.

Here is a program compiled by `gcc main.c -o main -lfftw3f -lm -std=c99` (may be different on your computer...). The flag `FFTW_FORWARD` is replaced by `FFTW_ESTIMATE`. And `#include <complex.h>` is placed before `#include <fftw3.h>` so that fftw can use the float complex type of `complex.h`

```
#include <complex.h>

#include <fftw3.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    int size [3] ={64, 128, 256};

    float *spatial = malloc(size[1]*size[1]*sizeof(float));
    if(spatial==NULL){fprintf(stderr,"malloc failed\n");exit(1);}
    fftwf_complex *fourier = fftwf_alloc_complex(size[1]*(size[1]/2+1));
    if(fourier==NULL){fprintf(stderr,"fftwf_alloc_complex failed\n");exit(1);}
    for(int i=0; i< size[1]; i++){
        for(int j=0; j<size[1]; j++){
            spatial[i*size[1]+j] =1; //fill spatial array;
        }
    }

    for(int i=0; i< size[1]; i++){
        for(int j=0; j<(size[1]/2+1); j++){
            fourier[i*(size[1]/2+1)+j]  =2.0+I ;//fill fourier array;
        }
    }

    fftwf_plan plan = fftwf_plan_dft_r2c_2d(size[1], size[1], spatial, fourier, FFTW_ESTIMATE);

    if(plan==NULL){printf("fftwf_plan_dft_r2c_2d : big problem %d\n",size[1]);fflush(stdout);}
    fftwf_execute(plan);


    printf("average is %g\n",creal(fourier[0])/(size[1]*size[1]));

    fftwf_destroy_plan(plan);
    free(fourier);
    free(spatial);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: How do you assign `2.0+I` to `fftwf_complex`? What is `I`?

Comment: [`I` is a macro defined in `complex.h`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/complex/I). It may expand to`_Complex_I`, that expands to a value of type `const float _Complex` with the value of the imaginary unit. Tahe a look at http://www.fftw.org/fftw3_doc/Complex-numbers.html : it is written `if you #include <complex.h> before <fftw3.h>, then fftw_complex is defined to be the native complex type and you can manipulate it with ordinary arithmetic (e.g. x = y * (3+4*I), where x and y are fftw_complex and I is the standard symbol for the imaginary unit);`.

Comment: I'd found that note in the documentation while trying to figure this out, and subsequently did the import, but it still uses the `float[2]` `fftwf_complex` type. Would be nice to use the cleaner c++ complex

Comment: The next paragraph of http://www.fftw.org/fftw3_doc/Complex-numbers.html suggests `To the extent that this is true, if you have a variable complex<double> *x, you can pass it directly to FFTW via reinterpret_cast<fftw_complex*>(x).`. See for instance the answer of Severin Pappadeux to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34750957/c-fftw-fast-fourier-transforms-with-complex-numbers .  I don't know if it is cleaner, but `std::complex<double>` is part of C++ and I don't know if it is feasible and beneficial to use it in a C code.

Comment: I only realised earlier that this code was `c`, and figured I had to prefix `complex` with `std::`, accordingly. I ended up just using my own basic `complex` struct