# C++ FFTW (fast fourier transforms) with complex numbers

Tags: c++, fft, fftw

I am trying to use FFT with complex numbers in C++. The problem is that I cannot make inner products, or sums of complex vectors with a common sintax, when using fftw_complex numbers.

Here is a reduced simple program:

```
#include <complex.h>
#include <fftw3.h>


int main(void){

int n=1024;
    fftw_complex *in, *out;
    fftw_plan p;

    in = (fftw_complex*) fftw_malloc(sizeof(fftw_complex) * n);
    out = (fftw_complex*) fftw_malloc(sizeof(fftw_complex) * n);
//  out = 1*in;   /!\
//  out = in+0;  / ! \

    p = fftw_plan_dft_1d(n, in, out, FFTW_FORWARD, FFTW_ESTIMATE);

    fftw_execute(p); /* repeat as needed */

    fftw_destroy_plan(p);
    fftw_free(in); fftw_free(out);

    return 0;
}
```

The two lines that are commented do not work:

i) the 1st one gives, when compiling:

```
test.cpp:13:10: error: invalid operands of types ‘int’ and ‘fftw_complex* {aka __complex__ double*}’ to binary ‘operator*’
```

ii) the 2nd one gives, during the execution:

```
*** glibc detected *** ./prog: corrupted double-linked list: 0x09350030 ***
```

Accordingly to the documentation of fftw.org [[link]](http://www.fftw.org/doc/Complex-numbers.html), standard sintax for manipulating fftw_complex should be accepted. Why not with vectors of fftw_complex?

For instance, I want to compute:

```
r = i*gamma_p*w/w0*m*exp(-l*z);
```

where i is the imaginary number; gamma_p, w0, and z are real numbers; w, m, and l are vectors of complex numbers.

I tried:

```
    fftw_complex* i_NUMBER = (fftw_complex*) fftw_malloc(1*sizeof(fftw_complex));
memset(i_NUMBER, 0, n*sizeof(fftw_complex));
    i_NUMBER[0][0]=0;
    i_NUMBER[0][1]=1;   //#real(i_NUMBER)=0; imag(i_NUMBER)=1; i.e. i_NUMBER=i;
fftw_complex* r = (fftw_complex*) fftw_malloc(n*sizeof(fftw_complex));

for (int i=0; i<n; i++){
    r[i] = i_NUMBER[0]*gamma_p*w[i]/w0*m[i]*pow(e_NUMBER, -l[i]*z);
}
```

but the compiler gives errors about the types of operands and operations.

```
gnlse.h:58:22: error: invalid operands of types ‘fftw_complex {aka double [2]}’ and ‘double’ to binary ‘operator*’
gnlse.h:58:61: error: wrong type argument to unary minus
```

Any help is welcome, thanks!

Comment: the lines:

 *out = (*in)+1;
 *out = (*in)+0;

solve the 1st problem.

Comment: what about the 2nd script?

Comment: C is not C++ is not C. Do not add unrelated tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to write explicit loops to works with vectors.

Line `out = in+0;` will produce two pointer pointing to the same location. When you deallocation it twice, you'll get corrupted heap

UPDATE

I think I know what problem might be. Default FFTW mode is C89. Automatic computations with complex numbers pretty much require either C99 mode or C++ using `<complex>` header. I would guess you picked some example, modified it and wondering why it doesn't work.

In C89 mode fftw_complex is just a double[2]. So any expression in C89 mode requires pretty much manual handling of the real and imag part, just what I proposed. Cannot mix in expression coerced-to-pointer complex and doubles, functions and expect automatic handling.

In C99 mode you could get native complex which makes working with them in expression a real treat wrt C89.

C++ native complex should work as well.

See http://www.fftw.org/doc/Complex-numbers.html for a detailed description.

My guess you're now effectively in C89 mode. You have to compile the example either with C99 (typically on linux /usr/bin/c99), or move to C++ and use C++ native complex along the line

```
#include <complex>

...

std::complex<double>* in  = new std::complex<double>[n];
std::complex<double>* out = new std::complex<double>[n];
...
p = fftw_plan_dft_1d(n,
                     reinterpret_cast<fftw_complex*>(in),
                     reinterpret_cast<fftw_complex*>(out),
                     FFTW_FORWARD, FFTW_ESTIMATE);
...
```

Comment: even with a loop, some operations cause errors - that can be seen in the last part of my message...

Comment: @sissi_luaty I believe you have to write separate code for real (indexed by 0) and imag (indexed by 1) parts.  In `i_NUMBER[0]*gamma_p` first argument is 2d double array, which is coerced to pointer, and second argument is just a double number. Compiler cannot deduce how to multiply pointer by double

Comment: I am trying r[i][0] = real(...); r[i][1] = imag(...);
but the compiler cannot do the maths

Comment: @sissi_luaty no, it is not a solution. You have to write expression on the right hand side using only doubles, so taking real and imag parts by hand

Comment: @sissi_luaty I think I got to the source of the problem - you expected something which won't work in your current setup, please see update